# Grant privileges to role query in Oracle not working

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I am trying to run below query in oracle db .

a. `GRANT UPDATE ON MIC_COMMON_AT.SHL_PRODUCERS TO MIC_READWRITE_AT;`

This query does not give any error and says `GRANT SUCCEEDED`.

b. But when I run below query to check this grant in `sys.all_tab_privs` for the role, to which this grant should have been added, it gives me 0 rows

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_tab_privs
WHERE GRANTEE  = 'MIC_READWRITE_AT';
```

I am not sure why the required grant for role(MIC_READWRITE_AT) is not getting inserted in `sys.all_tab_privs` table (query b returning 0 rows) - even though grant query for that role seems to execute successfully without any error (query a).

The user with which I am executing this query has been given dba role as default role, as well as it has the system privilege of '`GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE' AND "GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE`'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

all_tab_privs only includes object grants for which the current user is the object owner, grantor, or grantee. It won't show you grants on objects in other schemas. Try using the dba_tab_privs view instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This was actually very helpful.